# Very Slow Page - How to Optimize # of Queries?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, loop, optimization

**EDIT 12/19/2011**

Thank you again Ijaas.  Everything is working except for the order of the days.  It is ordering the groups of days by the publish order.  If an older post has a newer date in its meta_key then it is before a newer published post with an older meta_key.  It sorts the events on one day properly but it does not sort the days.

Do you have any idea why?

Here is the current code that I am using.

```
    <h1>Upcoming</h1>
<?php

$convertedtime = "Y-m-d H:i"; // Time format You can remove this if it is defined before
$convertedtime = "g:i"; // convert to 12 hour clock and minutes for upcomming events sidebar
$convertedendtime = "g:i a"; // convert to 12 hour clock and minutes for upcomming events sidebar
$today  = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' ); 
$thedate = time(); // IF you want to start from a future date use strtotime( FutureDateHere );
$thedate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $thedate );
$future = strtotime ( '+10 Days' ); // IF you want to start from a future date use strtotime( '+10 Days', strtotime( FutureDateHere ) );
$future = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $future );

$times  = array();
$events = array();

$keys = array('opening_time', 'closing_time', 'artist_talk_time', 'special_event_time', 'lecture_time', 'panel_time', 'workshop_time');

$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
 'order'       => 'asc',
 'meta_query' => array(
/* 'relation' => 'NONE',*/
    array(
        'key' => $keys,
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),

)
);

$event_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post(); 

    // Storing events in array is more efficent than using get_the_title, ect... later on
    $events[$post->ID] = array(
        'title'     => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title),
        'link'      => get_permalink($post->ID),
        'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'upcoming_event_sidebar'),
        'venue'     => get_post_meta($post->ID,'event_venue', true),
        'custom_venue' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'custom_event_venue', true),
        'opening_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time_end', true),
        'closing_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'closing_time_end', true),
        'artist_talk_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'artist_talk_time_end', true),
        'special_event_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'special_event_time_end', true),
        'lecture_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'lecture_time_end', true),
        'panel_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'panel_time_end', true),
        'workshop_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'workshop_time_end', true)
    );


    $custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();

    foreach ($custom_field_keys as $custom_field_key) {

        if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys)) {
            $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_key, true);
            if ($custom_field_value >= $thedate && $custom_field_value <= $future) {
                $times[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($custom_field_value))][] = array($custom_field_value, $post->ID, $custom_field_key);  
                $events[$post->ID][$custom_field_key] = $custom_field_value; //opening_time, closing_time.......

            }
        }
    }

endwhile;

    foreach($times as $day => $list): if($num = count($list)):

        sort($list);

        echo "<ul>"; // Start a day
        ?>
            <li class="sidebar_event_top">
                <h1>
                    <span class="total">
                        <?php echo $num.(($num >= 2)? " Events " : " Event "); ?>                    
                    </span> <!-- end .total -->
                    <span class="day_sidebar">
                        <?php echo ($day == $today)? "Today" : date( 'l', strtotime($day) ); ?>                
                    </span> <!-- end .day -->
                    <span class="date_sidebar">                    
                    <?php echo date( 'F j', strtotime($day) ); ?>
                    </span><!-- end .date -->
                </h1>
            </li>

        <?php

        foreach($list as $ev){

            $time_value = $ev[0]; $post_id = $ev[1]; $time_key = $ev[2];
            $e = (object) $events[$post_id];

            if ($time_key == 'opening_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Opening</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->opening_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->opening_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

            <?php } else if ($time_key == 'closing_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Closing</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                       <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->closing_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->closing_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

            <?php } else if ($time_key == 'artist_talk_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Artist Talk</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->artist_talk_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->artist_talk_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

            <?php } else if ($time_key == 'special_event_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Special Event</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->special_event_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->special_event_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

             <?php } else if ($time_key == 'lecture_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Lecture</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->lecture_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->lecture_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

             <?php } else if ($time_key == 'panel_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Panel</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->panel_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->panel_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

             <?php } else if ($time_key == 'workshop_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Workshop</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->workshop_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->workshop_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->
            <?php }
        }

        echo "</ul>"; // End a day

    endif; endforeach;



endif; // END $event_query->have_posts();

?>
```

I have a page that loops through a custom post type and sorts by dates entered in `meta_boxes`.  It seemed to work at a reasonable speed before but now it is extremely slow.  There is probably some logical mistake I am making in the order of my querys and php requests but I do not know how to optimize it.

Here is the code that is loaded on the page.

Link to **original**code on Pastebin for easier viewing:
[Pastebin Code](http://pastebin.com/5SsCr0Cv)

Here is the code from the functions.php that makes the meta data for the posts.
Link to Pastebin of this code section: [Meta Box Code](http://pastebin.com/RjHEjc5t)

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 12/14/2011 - Replaced original code with example below.  Am I on the right track?**  Original code still available at [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/5SsCr0Cv).

```
        <?php
    /* Let's get all the meta date in one call rather then so many queries */

    $event_custom_meta=get_post_custom($post->ID); // Get all the data 

    $event_start_date = $event_custom_meta['start_date'][0];  /* Not sure why I need [0] here but it returns Array if I don't have it */
    $event_end_date = $event_custom_meta['end_date'][0];
    $event_opening_time = $event_custom_meta['opening_time'][0];
    $event_closing_time = $event_custom_meta['artist_closing_time'][0];
    $event_lecture_time = $event_custom_meta['lecture_time'][0];
    $event_panel_time = $event_custom_meta['panel_time'][0];
    $event_special_event_time = $event_custom_meta['special_event_time'][0];
    $event_workshop_time = $event_custom_meta['workshop_time'][0];
    $event_event_venue = $event_custom_meta['event_venue'][0];
    $event_custom_event_venue = $event_custom_meta['custom_event_venue'][0];

    echo $event_start_date;
    echo $event_end_date;
    echo $event_opening_time;
    echo $event_closing_time;
    echo $event_artist_talk_time;
    echo $event_lecture_time;
    echo $event_panel_time;
    echo $event_special_event_time;
    echo $event_workshop_time;
    echo $event_event_venue;

    /* The test works. Alright, now I can echo these variables anyplace that I want */

    /* Replace the previous code below with the cleaner code after*/
    ?>
    <!-- old code -->
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?></a>

    <a href=""><h3><?php  

        if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'event_venue', true) != 'other') { 
            echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'event_venue', true);
            }
        if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'event_venue', true) == 'other') {
            echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'custom_event_venue', true);
            }
    ?></h3></a> 


    <!-- new code -->
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?></a>

    <a href=""><h3><?php  

        if ($event_event_venue != 'other') { 
            echo $event_event_venue;
            }
        if ($event_event_venue == 'other') {
            echo $event_custom_event_venue;
            }
    ?></h3></a> 
    <!-- end new code -->

   <?php 
   /* is calling the function get_related_event data another query?  
   *Is there away to add this infor to the orignial meta_box setup?
   */
   echo get_related_event_data( $event_event_venue, 'address' ); 
   echo get_related_event_data( $event_event_venue, 'phone_no' ); 
   echo get_related_event_data( $event_event_venue, 'url' ); 
   /* end question */
   ?>
```

**END EDIT on 12/14/2011 - added revised code example above**

I am pretty sure that it is in this section below, because the page speeds up when I take out the "Upcoming" loop.  What am I doing wrong?

Link to Suspicious section on Pastebin:[Suspicious Code](http://pastebin.com/4CcGML08)

```
<h1>Upcoming</h1>

  <?php
  for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $thedate = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
  $thedate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $thedate );

  $thedaytext = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $todaytext ) ) ;
  $thedaytext = date ( 'l' , $thedaytext );

  $thedatetext = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $todaydatetext ) ) ;
  $thedatetext = date ( 'F j' , $thedatetext );

  $future = strtotime ( '+24 hours' , strtotime ( $thedate ) ) ;
  $future = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $future ); 
  $times = array();  // put before the $event_query and seems to work

  $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'event',
       'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
       'order'       => 'asc',
       'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
              'key' => 'opening_time',
              'value' => array($today,$future),
              'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
              'type' => 'DATE'
          ),
          array(
              'key' => 'artist_talk_time',
              'value' => array($today,$future),
              'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
              'type' => 'DATE'
          ),
          array(
              'key' => 'closing_time',
              'value' => array($today,$future),
              'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
              'type' => 'DATE'
          ),
          array(
              'key' => 'special_event_time',
              'value' => array($today,$future),
              'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
              'type' => 'DATE'  
          )
      )
  );

  $event_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
  if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();  

  $keys = array('opening_time', 'closing_time', 'artist_talk_time', 'special_event_time');
  $custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();

  foreach ($custom_field_keys as $custom_field_key) {
     if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys)) {    
          $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_key, true);
          if ($custom_field_value >= $thedate && $custom_field_value <= $future) {
             $counttest++;
             $times[] = array($custom_field_value, $post->ID, $custom_field_key);
          }
      }
  }     

  endwhile;
  ?>

  <ul>

  <?php
  if ($counttest >0) {
  ?>
  <li>
  <h1 class="upcoming_date">
  <span class="total">
  <?php 
      echo $counttest;
      if ($counttest>=2) {
          echo ' Events ';
      } // end if ($totalevents>=2) function
      if ($counttest<2) { 
          echo ' Event ';
      }
  ?>

  </span> <!-- end .total -->
  <span class="day_sidebar">

  <?php
      if ($thedate==$today) {
          echo 'Today';
      }
      if ($thedate>$today) {
          echo $thedaytext;
      }
  ?>

  </span> <!-- end .day -->
  <span class="date_sidebar">

  <?php
      echo $thedatetext;
  ?>
  </span><!-- end .date -->
  </h1>
  </li>

  <?php
  }
  endif;
  $counttest=0;

  sort($times); // I changed the asort to sort here

       foreach ($times as $event) { $time_value = $event[0]; $post_id = $event[1]; $time_key = $event[2];  // changed the foreach here

      if ($time_key == 'opening_time') { ?>

      <li class="sidebar_event">
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'upcoming_event_sidebar'); ?></a> 

      <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
      <h3>Opening</h3>
      <h4>

   <?php
      if (get_post_meta($post_id,'event_venue', true) != 'other') { 
          echo get_post_meta($post_id,'event_venue', true);
          }
      if (get_post_meta($post_id,'event_venue', true) == 'other') {
          echo get_post_meta($post_id,'custom_event_venue', true);
          }

   ?> 
   </h4>
   <h5><?php $opening_time_formated = date($convertedtime, strtotime( get_post_meta($post_id,'opening_time', true)));
        echo $opening_time_formated;?> </h5>
            <hr />
      </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->
      <?php }

      else if ($time_key == 'artist_talk_time') { ?>

      <li class="sidebar_event">
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'upcoming_event_sidebar'); ?></a> 

      <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
      <h3>Artist Talk</h3>
      <h4><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id,'event_venue', true);?> </h4>
      <h5><?php $artist_talk_time_formated = date($convertedtime, strtotime( get_post_meta($post_id,'artist_talk_time', true)));
        echo $artist_talk_time_formated;?>  </h5>
      <hr />
      </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->
      <?php }

       else if ($time_key == 'closing_time') { ?>
       <li class="sidebar_event">
       <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'upcoming_event_sidebar'); ?></a> 

      <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
      <h3>Closing</h3>
      <h4><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id,'event_venue', true);?> </h4>
      <h5><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id,'closing_time', true);?> </h5>
      <hr />
      </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->
      <?php }

       else if ($time_key == 'special_event_time') { ?>
       <li class="sidebar_event">
       <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'upcoming_event_sidebar'); ?></a> 

      <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
      <h3>Special Event</h3>
      <h4><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id,'event_venue', true);?> </h4>
      <h5><?php $special_event_time_formated = date($convertedtime, strtotime( get_post_meta($post_id,'special_event_time', true)));
        echo $special_event_time_formated;?></h5>
      <hr />
      </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->
      <?php }

       }

        rewind_posts();
  ?>

  </ul>

  <?php
   }
   ?>
   <br />
  <br />
  </div>
```

Comment: y not simply make the future value '+10 days' and remove the for($i) loop? That will reduce your wp database queries from 10 to 1.

Comment: @ijaas   Thank you for the quick reply.  I thought I needed the `for(i$)` loop to grab the events for each individual day and only the events for that day.  If  I set the future value to +10 days, won't that only display events from the 10th day?

Comment: it can be done with one db query and without the for() loop. Will write a more detailed answer by the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry about the delay. Here is the condensed query that searchs for posts between today and 10 days into the future, then sorts and displays in them order.

theoretically it should work but let me know if u get any errors.

**Update: 12/22/2012 - Fixed Sorting**

```
<h1>Upcoming</h1>
<?php

$convertedtime = "Y-m-d H:i"; // Time format You can remove this if it is defined before
$convertedtime = "g:i"; // convert to 12 hour clock and minutes for upcomming events sidebar
$convertedendtime = "g:i a"; // convert to 12 hour clock and minutes for upcomming events sidebar
$today  = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' ); 
$thedate = time(); // IF you want to start from a future date use strtotime( FutureDateHere );
$thedate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $thedate );
$future = strtotime ( '+10 Days' ); // IF you want to start from a future date use strtotime( '+10 Days', strtotime( FutureDateHere ) );
$future = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $future );

$times  = array();
$events = array();

$keys = array('opening_time', 'closing_time', 'artist_talk_time', 'special_event_time', 'lecture_time', 'panel_time', 'workshop_time');

$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
 'order'       => 'asc',
 'meta_query' => array(
/* 'relation' => 'NONE',*/
    array(
        'key' => $keys,
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),

)
);

$event_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post(); 

    // Storing events in array is more efficent than using get_the_title, ect... later on
    $events[$post->ID] = array(
        'title'     => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title),
        'link'      => get_permalink($post->ID),
        'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'upcoming_event_sidebar'),
        'venue'     => get_post_meta($post->ID,'event_venue', true),
        'custom_venue' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'custom_event_venue', true),
        'opening_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time_end', true),
        'closing_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'closing_time_end', true),
        'artist_talk_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'artist_talk_time_end', true),
        'special_event_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'special_event_time_end', true),
        'lecture_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'lecture_time_end', true),
        'panel_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'panel_time_end', true),
        'workshop_time_end' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'workshop_time_end', true)
    );


    $custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();

    foreach ($custom_field_keys as $custom_field_key) {

        if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys)) {
            $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_key, true);
            if ($custom_field_value >= $thedate && $custom_field_value <= $future) {
                $times[strtotime($custom_field_value)][] = array($custom_field_value, $post->ID, $custom_field_key);  
                $events[$post->ID][$custom_field_key] = $custom_field_value; //opening_time, closing_time.......

            }
        }
    }

endwhile;

    ksort($times);

    foreach($times as $day => $list): if($num = count($list)):

        sort($list);

        echo "<ul>"; // Start a day
        ?>
            <li class="sidebar_event_top">
                <h1>
                    <span class="total">
                        <?php echo $num.(($num >= 2)? " Events " : " Event "); ?>                    
                    </span> <!-- end .total -->
                    <span class="day_sidebar">
                        <?php echo ($day == $today)? "Today" : date( 'l', $day ); ?>                
                    </span> <!-- end .day -->
                    <span class="date_sidebar">                    
                    <?php echo date( 'F j', $day ); ?>
                    </span><!-- end .date -->
                </h1>
            </li>

        <?php

        foreach($list as $ev){

            $time_value = $ev[0]; $post_id = $ev[1]; $time_key = $ev[2];
            $e = (object) $events[$post_id];

            if ($time_key == 'opening_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Opening</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->opening_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->opening_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

            <?php } else if ($time_key == 'closing_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Closing</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                       <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->closing_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->closing_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

            <?php } else if ($time_key == 'artist_talk_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Artist Talk</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->artist_talk_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->artist_talk_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

            <?php } else if ($time_key == 'special_event_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Special Event</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->special_event_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->special_event_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

             <?php } else if ($time_key == 'lecture_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Lecture</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->lecture_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->lecture_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

             <?php } else if ($time_key == 'panel_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Panel</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->panel_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->panel_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->

             <?php } else if ($time_key == 'workshop_time') { ?>

                <li class="sidebar_event">
                    <a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->thumbnail ?></a>                        
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $e->link ?>" title="<?php echo $e->title ?>"> <?php echo $e->title ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Workshop</h3>
                    <h4><?php echo ($e->venue != 'other')? $e->venue : $e->custom_venue; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo date( $convertedtime, strtotime( $e->workshop_time ) ); echo " - "; echo date( $convertedendtime, strtotime( $e->workshop_time_end ) ) ;?></h5>

                </li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->
            <?php }
        }

        echo "</ul>"; // End a day

    endif; endforeach;



endif; // END $event_query->have_posts();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ijaas.  Your code at the bottom really helped bring down the queries.  I am now having a problem with which dates are included.
I believe the problem is with this line
`$day = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($post->post_date));`
The post date or publish date is irrelevant. I only need to display posts that have meta values for each day. If `$post->post_date` is used then it displays posts based on the post date and displays old events (those with meta_keys older than today.
Any thoughts?

Comment: oops, yes u can use `get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time', true)` instead of `$post->post_date`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried that but it only gets the opening_time events.  Each post could have a time in any of the `$keys = array('opening_time', 'closing_time', 'artist_talk_time', 'special_event_time', 'lecture_time', 'panel_time', 'workshop_time');` `meta_key` slots.  It may have one date or all 7.  I tried ` $day = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( get_post_meta($post->ID, $keys, true)));` but that only returned events on January 1.  I also tried putting it in the `foreach` section but dates got out of order.  Any thoughts?  Thank you again.

Comment: try replace `$times[$day][] = array(...` with `$times[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($custom_field_value))][] = array(...`

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work.  At first the days were out of order but that might have been a problem with my database.  I am testing now with every combination of dates and time I can think of.  Does `$day` need to be defined in `foreach($times as $day => $list): if($num = count($list)):`  ?  Also in`$events[$post->ID] = array( 'title' => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title), 'link' => get_permalink($post->ID), ...`  You use `get_post_meta` twice.  Is that efficient to also grab all ending times? It would be 7 more `get_post_meta`

Comment: yes the `$day` needs to be defined for use in the first `<h1>` tag. The `get_post_meta` function does not make a db call, as all meta values for the posts are cached by the `WP_Query` function so it isn't a problem to make multiple get_post_meta queries.

Comment: Thank you again.  Thank you again Inaas.  Everything is working except for the order of the days.  It is ordering the groups of days by the publish order.  If an older post has a newer date in its meta_key then it is before a newer published post with an older meta_key.  It sorts the events on one day properly but it does not sort the days.  I posted the current code in the question section.

Comment: I tried `'orderby => 'none',` but that didn't seem to work.  The days are out of order.

Comment: adding `sort($times);` before the `foreach` loop should do the trick. If it doesn't i will look into it and update my answer.

Comment: I tried putting `sort($times);` before each of the `foreach` loops, (one at a time).  It doesn't seem to sort the days and it displays all the days as January 1.

Comment: i updated my answer with what should fix the sorting of days.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  That did the trick.  Now I just need to figure out how to get an `else: echo "something";` statement in the `if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();  ` but that is for another question.  I will try to figure it out myself first.  Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. the `else:` statement is easy just add it right before the last line `endif; // END $event_query->have_posts();`

Comment: I tried that code in that exact place before but it didn't work.  Now it does.  I must have typed something wrong when I did it the first time.  Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I see that will very likely speed this up.

Use the native time parameters in WP Query first and then do your custom "stuff": http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters

Use `get_post_custom` instead of `get_post_meta`:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Comment: @Wrck  Thank you for the reply.  To clarify, I am not trying to show posts with a publish date in a certain range, I am show posts that have a meta_key that is a text string date that falls withing a certain range.  It seems that the WP time parameters are for post dates and not meta_keys.  Am I wrong in thinking this?  I tried to replace `get_post_meta' with 'get_post_custom` but got errors.  I will continue to read the Codex to figure it out.  I am still not sure how to stream line the time parameters either but will try my best.  Suggestions and hints are welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: I understand now that I need to use `get_post_custom`  That should lower the DB queries.  The problem is I am not sure how to implement it efficiently. Currently it just echos Array any time I use it.  I imagine that I need to use `get_post_custom` and have it set all the `met_keys` to a set of variables and then use the variables in the if statements to display the content in the right order.  Still wracking my brain.

Comment: Ya basically returning an array is 1 db query as opposed to many, then you have to parse the array though. As for 'the time',  since they are "custom dates", I was somewhat confused. I think to optimize this you might not want to churn through all that cpu on one page load and possibly store some of this data in the transient API, especially of this data does not change more than a few times every hour.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I am still having issues outputing everything. I can get a large array to print but it has a lot of extra information.  I should be able to figure it out and get it at least a bit more efficient.   I am not sure what a "transient API" is so I will be looking that up and trying to implement it.  That would be great if it stored the info once every couple of hours. Now how to do it?

Comment: I added a `[0]` to the end of the `get_post_custom` and it is grabbing the information now.  I posted an example variable set up at the top of this page.  Is that what I am supposed to do?  Thanks again.

Comment: Well a `[0]` will grab the first key in the array, you have to be somewhat familiar with php here, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, for the transient API as well, http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: @Wcyk   Thank you for all your help.  I have to accept this answer since I am much farther along.  I still have a question about selecting the second key in the array.  Each time I try with`[1]` it doesn't seem to work.  I posted my `meta_box' code at the top of the question.  If you have any insights as to why it is not working I would really appreciate.  In any event, thank you for the help and I will be reading up all week on arrays.  I am familiar with php and logic but am not formally trained.

Comment: OK ya , your code is quite complex for one answer, it might be best to post 1 problem/snippet at a time, it's looks like you have multi-dimensional arrays ( arrays inside arrays) so you would grab them using something along the lines of `echo $array[0][5];` , typically with an array you loop through it as well with something like `foreach ($array as $color) {
    echo "$color";
}`